# Haml is erasing javascript

Tags: javascript, haml

I am implementing a custom form for stripe. I am getting an error stating that there is no card entered when I put in one. I checked by current file which contains this javascript:

```
:javascript
Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_key');
$('#payment-form').submit(function(event) {
  var form = $(this);
  form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);
  Stripe.createToken(form, stripeResponseHandler);
  return false;
});
function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
  var form = $('#payment-form');
  if (response.error) {
    form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    var token = response.id;
    form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken">').val(token));
    form.get(0).submit();
  }
```

But when I see the javascript that is actually formed in the browser all i see is this:

```
var form = $(this);
          form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);
          Stripe.createToken(form, stripeResponseHandler);
          return false;


          var form = $('#payment-form');
          if (response.error) {
            form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
            form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
          } else {
            var token = response.id;
            form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken">').val(token));
            form.get(0).submit();
          }
```

I contacted stripe support and said my javascript is correct but when it's rendered through haml it's coming out wrong. Does anybody know of a way to stop haml from removing sections of my javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire filtered block must be indented as per the docs:

http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#filters

Note only your indented JS is being rendered.

Comment: Thank you so much... I never new that haml javascript needs to be indented too